# How to merge MIDI tracks

Tags: midi

I'm currently (well was) recording in a studio and we use MIDI for certain instrumentation.

When I received the midi track from the producer he had managed to separate every MIDI track into single notes: there was a single midi track for each note line for each instrument.

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to simply merge the midi tracks into one.
I'm trying to refrain from having to move each note track into the others.

I'm currently using the following programs: Guitar pro, Reason, FL Studio.

If someone could provide me with some insight I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combine MIDI files](http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/9402/combine-midi-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an author. I have *4 published books* which I used MIDI *for all the processes.* I recommend you to use **Sibelius or Finale** for any kind of MIDI notation issues. They are *very friendly working* with MIDI instruments as well.

[Sibelius](http://www.sibelius.com/home/index_flash.html),
[Finale](http://www.finalemusic.com)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a few different ways to collapse and merge those MIDI files quickly. I use [REAPER](http://www.reaper.fm/) as my primary DAW, so I'm going to reference possible solutions in that package. Reaper does have a fully functional, open-ended trial version, so no worries there. There are two main strategies I see though in any package:

1. Implode all MIDI tracks and then glue together
2. Record MIDI output of all tracks into one new MIDI master track

You can find an excellent resource detailing how to do this exactly in REAPER over at their [official forum](http://forum.cockos.com/showthread.php?t=26054). But it's essentially just a few right-clicks away.

Comment: Couldn't post more than two links in the original post, but check out this screencast (http://www.screencast.com/t/7DNF4IOD) to see the implode / glue strategy in action. It should give you an idea of whether it will work for your scenario or not. I don't have REAPER in front of me now, but I don't see any challenge with selecting and imploding many tracks at once (instead of the two shown in the video).

Also, I'm assuming that the MIDI tracks are all keeping the same time, but are just blank when the note isn't playing. Let me know if that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

if you r in a studio then you should be able to pull two midis in a programm like reason  / ableton propeller. Pull it Together and it should be joined + you choose what instruments are supposed to be used instead of the Midi Original.